# How do you change WPF DataGrid cell background while editing the cell?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

The following is an example of how to set the background when the cell is selected, but when I actually click inside the cell to edit it the color changes. Is there a trigger property for when a cell is being edited? I'd like the background not to change.

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SeaGreen"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answering my own question, it looks like the Cell background color is based off of `SystemColors.WindowBrushKey`. Overriding that resource like such `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Red" />` did the trick.
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add another trigger into your existing style for the `IsEditing` state. Then you can set the `ControlTemplate` for the `DataGridCell` inside of the trigger.

```
<Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="SeaGreen"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Nice solution, one problem though: the textbox doesn't automatically focus. In order to automatically focus on the textbox, add the following attribute to the textbox's declaration: FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Comment: Works fine, but only if all columns is of type DataGridTextColumn. If there is column of other type, say DataGrigTemplateColumn with CheckBox, then after clicking on the cell it becomes TextBox instead of CheckBox. Any suggestion how to differentiate column type in trigger?

Answer (score 0):

This works with DataGridTemplateColumn as well as other types like DataGridTextColumn, DataGridCheckboxColumn and etc.:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border x:Name="CellBorder"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                            
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="CellBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter TargetName="CellBorder" Property="Background" Value="yellow" />
                        <Setter TargetName="CellBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```